# setting user session in laravel by user_name or user_id

Tags: html, session, authentication, laravel, usersession

I want to set user session in laravel, same as we can do it in core php using following code

```
<?php session_start();  

if(!isset($_SESSION["user_name"])) 

{ header("Location:index.php?msg=Please log in");

}else{
$sql="UPDATE users SET log_time = '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'
WHERE id=".$_SESSION['id'];
$res = mysql_query($sql);
}
?>
```

I want to make session in laravel either by user_id or by user_name.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides direct support for Session using its Session class

```
use Session; // at top of class
if (!Session::has('user_id'))
{
     return Redirect::to('index.php?msg=Please log in');
}
else
{
      $sql="UPDATE users SET log_time = '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'
      WHERE id=".Session::get('user_id');
      $res = mysql_query($sql);

}
```

EDIT:

also laravel provides support for Eloquent model so do not write queires like that, just follow this structure

```
$user = User::find(Session::get('user_id'));
$user->log_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$user->update();
```

Comment: where you have written this code ? its should be written in controller

Comment: can you please tell me what you are trying to ? so that i can give you best way to do in Laravel

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Redirect' not found , it is the error, I am using 
WelcomeController in the Controller directiry, and I put this code after the clase deffinitions like use db; etc.

Comment: can you please tell me what you are trying to do ?

Comment: i have set a log in simple log in system using laravel. I want to set user session now. that s it